# Randomly 403 HTTP Status from IIS

Tags: iis, webforms, http-status-code-403

I have a ASP.NET (4.7.2) WebForms application who run from long time. Since some days, for one ASPX page (always the same), users randomly receive 403 status.
I activate trace on IIS (10) and I see this detail :

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS - Warning
ModuleName="ManagedPipelineHandler", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="403", HttpReason="Forbidden", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully. (0x0)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""

On the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code#403---forbidden), the substatus 0 is not mentionned.

I don't know what to do next. The error occurs 3 or 4 time per day.

Any ideas ?

**Edit 1**

When I compare two IIS traces for the same page (status 403 and status 200), I see what in the 403 trave, the following ASP.NET page events are missing :

- PreRender
- SaveViewState
- Render
  To go further, I override in my page following events with log and call to base :
- OnPreRender
- OnPreRenderComplete
- OnSaveStateComplete
- OnUnoad
  And after another status 403, I see in my logs that avents OnPreRender, OnPreRenderComplete and OnSaveStateComplete are missing.

How can I go further to find why these events are not called ?

- OnUnload

Comment: You didn't find things from IIS documentation, which is expected. Web apps themselves can return certain error codes, and in your case this is very likely the case. People need to combine FRT trace file with the actual web app source code to decide what's the next step. Hire an experienced consultant, or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com please.

Comment: According to your description, has this problem not occurred before? I think you can check whether there have been any recent changes in the current environment, such as whether any configurations have been changed, or system updates/patches have been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all ideas and response. Finally, the 403 was returned by our application (we use an opaque private framework...). The problem is now corrected.

Answer (score -1):

There's something wrong in your web.config, a path to a request handler is not right. Verify all of the path information is correct in the  section of your web.config. Here's an MSDN article that discusses [registering HTTP handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx).

Comment: I doubt that's where the problem lies, as the error only occurs occasionally and at random.

Comment: FRT log entry above actually indicated the right handler has been located but it returned 403.0. So, this isn't the right answer.